# How to identify the most different short sequence from a corpus that does not occur?

Tags: search

I would like to generate the most unique string (20 long, primer) of a defined length that does  **not**  occur in a much larger string (6.4 billion long, human genome). Of course, there could be many unique strings, but I want to avoid string with any mismatches/deletions/insertions that could occur in the larger stringer. My problem is easier than regular text because there only 4 possible elements (A, T, C, G) in the string, but I also need to worry about the reverse complement of the unique string that might occur in the larger string.

I have tried identifying these unique string by brute force search for mismatch, but I was wondering if there is better method. For bioinformatics experts, I did a BLAST search against the genome from a randomly generated string.

Comment: So you want a string that is unique even if there are insertions, deletions, or substitutions? If so, you must mean a string that is beyond a certain cost from anything else.

Comment: Start with a simple $k$mer analysis. This’ll allow you to construct the words that don’t appear, or at least the least frequent. Then compute the Smith-Waterman scores of these in comparison with the genome. Select those with the lowest scores.